# Reading off module properties from the companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characteristic-polynomial, companion-matrices

Let $P\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$, and $M_P$ its [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). The matrix $M_P$ gives a module of $\mathbb{F}[x]$ on $\mathbb{F}^n$, by letting $x\cdot w= M_P\cdot w$ for $w \in \mathbb{F}^n$.

This $\mathbb{F}[x]$-module is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}[x]/(P)$ and therefore cyclic, true? It is simple iff $P$ is irreducible, right? When is it indecomposable? When is it semisimple?

Comment: Yes, it's cyclic and it's simple iff $P$ is irreducible. It's semisimple iff $P$ is squarefree, and I think it's indecomposable iff $P$ has one irreducible factor. All of this follows from the structure theorem.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How would one go about proving this?

Comment: Like I said, all of this follows from the structure theorem (for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain). Are you familiar with what this says for finitely generated $F[x]$-modules?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think so. The primary decomposition says that any finitely generated $F[x]$-module $M$ is isomorphic to the product of quotients of the regular $F[x]$-module, i.e. $M\cong F[x]/(P_1)\times \ldots F[x]/(P_n)$. The $P_i$’s are irreducible polynomials unique up to multiplication by constant polynomials and up to reordering.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If $P$ is square free, then we can apply the Chinese remainder theorem and decompose $M=F[x]/(P)$ into a product of $F[x]/(P_i)$'s, where all the polynomials $P_i$ appearing in the quotient are irreducible. Why are these quotients irreducible $F[x]$-modules then? Conversely, if $P$ is not square free, in $M$'s (essentially unique) primary decomposition, there appears a submodule $F[x]/(P_i)^k$ where $P_i$ is an irreducible polynomial and $k>1$. I am trying to argue that then the submodule $P_i (F[x]/(P_i)^k)$ doesn’t have a complement in $M$, but why?

Comment: If I could show that, then the implication '$P$ has one irreducible factor $\Rightarrow$ $M$ is indecomposable' would also follow. If $M$ has more than one irreducible factor, then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem it is decomposable.

Comment: @Magaret: over a commutative ring $R$ we have the following: the simple modules are exactly the quotients $R/m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal. Also the endomorphism ring of a cyclic module $R/I$ is $R/I$ itself, so it is indecomposable iff $R/I$ has no nontrivial idempotents. Now show that $F[x]/P_i^k$ has this property.